# EU countries with regions and population density per each country's region

Tags: data-request, europe, population

I'm trying to create a Europe map with countries in it with Leaflet. Is there a resource that has structured data about each of EU country within regions with population density per region?

Comment: wikipedia/wikidata. what have you done to find this resource(s)?

Comment: https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/databrowser/view/demo_r_gind3/default/table?lang=en (it's only an internet search away)